# How can I get all tokens listed on `Sushiswap`

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, factory, sushiswap, uniswapv2

How can I get all tokens listed on `Sushiswap`. For `uniswap` we can call `factory.getTokenWithId(id)` with the token id. But how can we do the same for `Sushiswap` ?

Comment: [You can find example Python code here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/) for querying all `PairCreated` events and building a pair and token list.

Answer (score 3):

The SushiSwap subgraph provides a GraphQL API that you can query to get information about tokens, pairs, and other relevant data.  You can find the SushiSwap subgraph URL on their official documentation or [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sushiswap/subgraphs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any no proper documentation?